# Can't skip images in Fotos

Tags: release-freya, applications

I just installed Fotos from the "Made for Elementary" App Store-App and have a small problem.

When I open an image that is located in a folder of more images I can't skip to the next image either by using the GUI arrows, the arrow keys on the keyboard or the space bar. What am I missing here?

[image: screenshot]

[image: version]

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug. see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/foto/+bug/1088109).

you may consider to confirm ... consider confirming the bug !

The available version of foto is 1.0 which is testing, see [here](https://launchpad.net/foto).

In the bug report- status: Fix commited.

> Fix Committed  means:
>   Fixed, but not available until next release.

Comment: I don't think this bug report describes my problem. What I want to do is:
1. open a folder of images in files
2. open one of the images
3. then by clicking the arrow keys(gui or keyboard) or space bar -> go to next image

so there is only one window open at the time and the user can go through a whole folder of images.

Comment: Well, I understand your question and I too have same issue. I am opening new bug report now :) reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/foto/+bug/1523207)

Comment: @hrvstr If you have launchpad account, please add yourself to the affecting list [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/foto/+bug/1523207/+affectsmetoo)